# Tkinter Canvas Color

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I have this scrolled frame class:

```
 class ScrolledFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kw):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kw)
        # create a canvas object and a vertical scrollbar for scrolling it
        canvas = Canvas(self)
        canvas.config(width = 1000, height = 900)
        vscrollbar = Scrollbar(self, orient=VERTICAL,command=canvas.yview)
        vscrollbar.pack(fill=Y, side=RIGHT)
        hscrollbar = Scrollbar(self, orient=HORIZONTAL,command=canvas.xview)
        hscrollbar.pack(fill=X, side=BOTTOM)
        canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vscrollbar.set)
        canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=hscrollbar.set)
        canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=TRUE)

        # reset the view
        canvas.xview_moveto(0)
        canvas.yview_moveto(0)

        # create a frame inside the canvas which will be scrolled with it
        self.interior = interior = Frame(canvas)
        interior_id = canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=interior,
                                           anchor=NW)

        # track changes to the canvas and frame width and sync them,
        # also updating the scrollbar
        def _configure_interior(event):
            # update the scrollbars to match the size of the inner frame
            size = (interior.winfo_reqwidth(), interior.winfo_reqheight())
            canvas.config(scrollregion="0 0 %s %s" % size)
            if interior.winfo_reqwidth() != canvas.winfo_width():
                # update the canvas's width to fit the inner frame
                canvas.config(width=interior.winfo_reqwidth())
        interior.bind('<Configure>', _configure_interior)
```

I call it in my application like this:

```
class Application(Frame):
  self.root() = Tk()
```

the usual code after....

```
  self.frame = ScrolledFrame(self.root)
  self.frame.pack()

  self.statusFrame = Frame(self.frame.interior,borderwidth = 1)
  self.statusFrame.pack(side = TOP, fill = X)
```

I have tried canvas.config(bg = 'black') in the ScrolledFrame class and self.frame.interior.config(bg = 'black'), but the color of my canvas doesn't change. How can I change the background color?

Thanks!

Comment: When I insert `canvas.config(background="black")` in the above code, the window turns black for me. Are you _certain_ the above code won't yield a black canvas when you change the background? Can you show code where you try to set the background, so we can see how you are doing it?

Comment: I see you add a frame 'self.interior' on top of the canvas. Is this what is covering your canvas ?

Comment: A lot of frames are covering the scrollable canvas. I actually see a black edge  where no frames are over the canvas. It seems to me I have to change the color of all the top layer frames. Is there no way to just set a default background to everything?

Comment: @bluebird343, you could include a method that gets the children of your parent window and uses the `config` method on each to give them all the same color.